# What is the absolute best theoretical lossless compression of data possible?

Tags: machine-learning, compression, artificial-intelligence

To start with:

Assume that the algorithm takes finite space.
Assume that the computational resources are infinite.

What form would the result of such compression take? My intuition tells me it would it be some form of a pRNG-like algorithm with an irreducible seed that gives rise to the compressed data. Could there be something even more efficient?

Now what if we assume all resources are finite. Would the problem of perfect compression equate to the problem of perfect pattern recognition? What form would the result of such compression take? Factorization into primes? Something else? And would having such an algorithm imply that the problem of AI has been cracked?

As a side question, has there been successful attempts to use machine learning for data compression?

Comment: You may find the information at http://www.hutter1.net/ai/ helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There is a mathematical proof that your question cannot be answered in general.  The best compression possible is not computable.  See [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

Compression only works when the data can be modeled in some way to expose redundancy.